# SQLite3 no da fallo al insertar referencia inexistente

Tags: sql, sqlite3, sqlite

Estoy trabajando contra una base de datos en SQLite3 y me ha sorprendido el poder insertar una línea con una referencia a otra tabla el la cual no existe la fila correspondiente con la clave foránea.

El siguiente ejemplo mínimo ilustra la situación.

```
jdura@thinkpad:~/t$ sqlite3  
SQLite version 3.8.11.1 2015-07-29 20:00:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(  NOMBRE TEXT NOT NULL  , CIUDAD TEXT,  
   ...>   PRIMARY KEY( NOMBRE));    
sqlite> CREATE TABLE OTROS_DATOS(  NOMBRE TEXT NOT NULL, CANTIDAD INTEGER ,  
   ...>   PRIMARY KEY( NOMBRE),    
   ...>   FOREIGN KEY(NOMBRE)  REFERENCES CLIENTE(NOMBRE)  
   ...>       ON DELETE CASCADE  
   ...>       ON UPDATE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);  
sqlite> INSERT INTO CLIENTE( NOMBRE, CIUDAD) VALUES("JUAN", "CUZCO");  
sqlite> SELECT * FROM CLIENTE;  
JUAN|CUZCO  
sqlite> INSERT INTO OTROS_DATOS( NOMBRE, CANTIDAD) VALUES( "JUAN", 7);  
sqlite> SELECT * FROM OTROS_DATOS;  
JUAN|7  
sqlite> INSERT INTO OTROS_DATOS(NOMBRE, CANTIDAD) VALUES( "NO EXISTE", 27); /*   
   ...>   ^^^^ Esperaba fallo por referencia no satisfecha */;  
sqlite> SELECT * FROM OTROS_DATOS; /* Pero la línea sí se ha insertado */;  
JUAN|7  
NO EXISTE|27  
sqlite> INSERT INTO OTROS_DATOS(NOMBRE, CANTIDAD) VALUES( "NO EXISTE", 27); /*  
   ...>   ^^^^ Aquí  sí que falla, al menos los cámpos únicos funcionan */;  
SQL error: column NOMBRE is not unique  
sqlite>
```

Como indico en el comentario esperaba que fallase el insertar una línea en la tabla `OTROS_DATOS` con referencia al cliente `"NO EXISTE"`, el cual no existe en la tabla `CLIENTE`.

¿Cómo tengo que crear las tablas para que se respete la integridad referencial?.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

sqlite tiene deshabilitada por defecto la integridad referencial. Puedes habilitarla ejecutando:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON
```

La habilitación no es persistente. Hay que hacerlo **cada vez** que se conecta a la base de datos.

Comment: Es importante mencionar que es necesario hacerlo *cada vez* que conectas al base de datos.